# Spotfire idle screen deactivation

Tags: spotfire

in regard to spotfire inactivity screen,
can i disable that feature somehow? I need to set a screen always displaying a dashboard but with no interaction and i cannot do that because of the server logging out after some inactivity time.
Will a simple mouse jiggler do the trick?

Comment: what version of Spotfire are you using?

Comment: Build Version: 7.8.0.1.34

Answer (score 1):

besides changing the global inactivity timeout (probably not an ideal solution, but I will happily edit to include instructions), you (or your Spotfire admin) can put the analysis on a Scheduled Update. I am going to assume that your Spotfire instance is already configured to allow Scheduled Updates as per [the admin manual](https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-spotfire-analyst-7-8-0).

I've done this before and I'm 95% sure this will sidestep the inactivity timeout, but it's been a while, so please try this and reply if it doesn't work for some reason.

to create a scheduled update for an analysis...

1. log in to the Spotfire server as an administrator or a user with permissions to create Scheduled Updates
2. click **Schedules and Routing**
3. click the **Create Rule** button
4. leave the selector on **FILE** and click **Next**
5. give a name for the schedule and browse to the file in the library
6. leaving other settings at their defaults, click **Create new schedule**
7. tick the days you'd like this analysis to remain loaded, set the time range it should be loaded on those days. set the *Check for updates every ...* to your update range (I suggest something like five minutes but it's up to you), then click **Save**
8. you're done! click **Save** again

now while you have the analysis open, it will reload itself every five minutes with the current data.

I would avoid setting it to something like ~1 minute as this could, depending on the amount of data being loaded; how many users you have; the complexity of the analysis; etc., consume too many server resources. keep in mind Spotfire is not for "real time" analysis but for "data at rest." we (Tibco) do offer products for real time data visualization like LiveView and Streambase, but they are separate from Spotfire (from a licensing perspective. I believe they can be integrated in fun ways).

Comment: Thank you very much! Does scheduling updates to a report means all the data is going to load again? that seems to be a little to extensive in time and resources. Also, we have the reports on touch screens for managers to surf on them, will updates cause a bad user experience?

Comment: Yes, when a scheduled update fires it will reload the data. To avoid overextending the server you have to manage the schedule. Most of my customers have loaded the larger reports during the wee hours and then let them expire after end of business (6a-8p, eg) so that users don’t experience any disruption. However unless you set the update to “force update” (check exact wording; I can’t at the moment), users who have the analysis open during the update will continue using the “stale” data, and will be notified as such by a little red ! in the corner. Check the manual for more specifics.